# Failing to debug Nginx load-balancer

Tags: perl, nginx, docker, load-balancing

I'm trying to set up a load balancer using Nginx for a perl Dancer2 app which runs inside docker containers. 
And i have this problem i don't know how to debug:
If in my `nginx.conf`  i set  just one server in to the `upstrem block it runs fine.` But the second i add an other server it fails to execute login
My `nginx.conf` file looks like this:

```
worker_processes 2;
events { worker_connections 512; }
http {


    upstream pb {

        server pearlbee:5000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; 
        server pearlbee2:5000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s; 
    }



    server {

    listen *:80;
        location / {


        proxy_pass http://pb;


        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


        #proxy_redirect     off;
        #proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }

 }

}
```

My `docker-compose` file looks like this :

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      # here i pass my configuration to nginx 
       - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - pearlbee  
    volumes_from:
      - pearlbee  
  pearlbee:
    build: pearlbee
    command: carton exec  starman   bin/app.psgi
    #ports:
     #- "5000:5000"

    volumes:
      - ./config.yml:/config.yml  
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret

    depends_on:
      - mysql
  pearlbee2:
    build: pearlbee
    command: carton exec  starman   bin/app.psgi
    ports:
     - "5000"

    volumes:
      - ./config.yml:/config.yml  
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret

    depends_on:
      - mysql    
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_USER=root
```

Comment: What does the "fails to execute login" look like? a 502 error? something else?

Comment: It looks like your pearlbee and pearlbee2 service are identical. It might be better to define only one service, and then scale it to two instances with `docker-compose scale pearlbee=2`

Comment: Its not an 502 error it just returns me to the same page ....

Comment: As programmerq said, the services are identical if they're the same server. If you're only running one server, change the port number to something else

Comment: I've deleted my 'pearlbee2 service' and played with docker-compose scale pearlbee=2. It starts new instances of pearlbee but when i checked inside the 'nginx container' with 'nslookup' igot only one ip listed. So i think that the load balancer doset work poperly. The output of `nslookup`was : `Address 1: 172.22.0.5 settingupnginx_pearlbee_1.settingupnginx_default` @programmerq @Keenan Lawrence

Comment: Take a look at my github repository I created to illustrate how all this works: https://github.com/programmerq/scaletest

If you try to resolve `pearlbee`, it should return all the containers associated with that service.

Comment: Thanks you very much programmerq adding a resolver like your example suggest added the missing containers. @programmerq

Comment: so what was the solution? i'm using https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy which acutally can configure it for you automatically. however you hadn't specifed the error so i guess you solved it?